# best way to query on over 15m rows?

Tags: database, postgresql, solr, replication, scalability

I have a table that has over 15m rows in Postgresql. The users can save these rows (let's say items) into their library and when they request their library, the system loads the user's library.

The query in Postgresql is like

```
SELECT item.id, item.name 
FROM items JOIN library ON (library.item_id = item.id) 
WHERE library.user_id = 1
```

, the table is already indexed and denormalized so I don't need any other JOIN.

If a user has many items in the library (like 1k items) the query time increases normally. (for example for 1k items the query time is 7s) My aim is to reduce the query time for large datasets.

I already use Solr for full-text searching, and I tried queries like `?q=id:1 OR id:100 OR id:345` but I'm not sure whether it's efficient or not in Solr.

I want to know my alternatives for querying this datasets. The bottleneck in my system seems disk speed. Should I buy a server that has over 15gb memory and go with Postgresql in increased `shared_memory` option or try something like Mongodb or another memory based databases, or should I create a cluster system and replicate the data in Postgresql?

```
items:
    Column    |       Type        
 --------------+-------------------
  id           | text              
  mbid         | uuid              
  name         | character varying
  length       | integer          
  track_no     | integer          
  artist       | text[]            
  artist_name  | text            
  release      | text              
  release_name | character varying
  rank         | numeric          

user_library:

    Column    |            Type             |                              Modifiers
--------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 user_id      | integer                     | not null
 recording_id | character varying(32)       |
 timestamp    | timestamp without time zone | default now()
 id           | integer                     | primary key nextval('user_library_idx_pk'::regclass)


-------------------

explain analyze 
SELECT recording.id,name,track_no,artist,artist_name,release,release_name
FROM recording JOIN user_library ON (user_library.recording_id = recording.id)
WHERE user_library.user_id = 1;

 QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..10745.33 rows=1036539 width=134) (actual time=0.168..57.663 rows=1000 loops=1)
   Join Filter: (recording.id = (recording_id)::text)
   ->  Seq Scan on user_library  (cost=0.00..231.51 rows=1000 width=19) (actual time=0.027..3.297 rows=1000 loops=1) (my opinion: because user_library has only 2 rows, Postgresql didn't use index to save resources.)
         Filter: (user_id = 1)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..10.49 rows=2 width=165) (actual time=0.045..0.047 rows=1 loops=1000)
         ->  Seq Scan on recording  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=196) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=1000)
         ->  Index Scan using de_recording3_table_pkey on de_recording recording  (cost=0.00..10.49 rows=1 width=134) (actual time=0.040..0.042 rows=1 loops=1000)
               Index Cond: (id = (user_library.recording_id)::text)
 Total runtime: 58.589 ms
(9 rows)
```

Comment: Why you are loading 1K+ rows in memory ? Surely you don't show all of them to user screen at once ?

Comment: I didn't meant to load only spesific rows into memory. I meant to load all 15m rows and work in memory. It really speeds up the query but I need extra ~8gb memory.

Comment: Show the result of `explain` on your query

Comment: And what if you have more than 1 server ? How would you handle updates/inserts ? Memory speeds things up but has its costs. Can you just work with a subset of your data at once ? BTW, is this a web app ?

Comment: This really isn't an answer, but you might consider combining the user assignments with the item entries themselves. Yes it duplicates the assignment data, but in return for the extra manual work you avoid the cost of the join. This sort of trick will become more important as your dataset grows.

Comment: @Clodoaldo I'm not be able to access the server at this time but the query use indexes and does not have any problem.

Comment: @Joe C: would't this cripple caching capabilities on the DB server ? IMO it should be measured if that approach would make better perfs.

Comment: If you are asking about performance or scalability you must show not only the `explain` but also your table's creation statements. That is much saner than speculating about exotic solutions upfront.

Comment: @PetarRepac yes it's a web app. I know keeping all data in memory is not the answer but maybe a master/slave system can work for me.

Comment: @JoeC. it's not a good way for me because item entries has more than 10 columns and it would be a nightmare after a while. :/

Comment: @Clodoaldo, here it is: http://pastebin.com/DDxgc6Lh (don't forget it's in development mode)

Comment: @hobaba: so, you retrieve all items in all user libraries and render then into html and return them to user ?

Comment: I guess that _query time_ of 7s is not really query time but retrieval time. The time it takes to transfer the 1k rows from the server to the client. What is the client and how are you measuring query time? If you do `explain analyze` it will show real query time.

Comment: On a side-note, I think you mean `shared_buffers` not `shared_memory` - and no, if you add RAM don't increase `shared_buffers` that much. More RAM is still extremely good though, it lets the OS cache the disk contents in memory.

Comment: @Clodoaldo actually I executed query raw query before explain analyze so it cached all rows into the memory before I run explain analyze. I use navicat (sql client for desktop) to measure the query time.

Comment: @CraigRinger yep, you're right. however shared_buffers guarantees that the system has enough memory to run postgresql with increased memory.

Answer (score 2):

First, if your interesting (commonly used) set of data fits comfortably in memory as well as all indexes, you will have much better performance so yes, more RAM will help.  However, with 1k records, part of your time will be spent on materializing records and sending them to the client.

A couple other initial points:

1. There is no substitute for real profiling.  You may be surprised as to where the time is being spent.  On PostgreSQL use explain analyze to do profiling of a query.
2. Look into cursors and limit/offset.

I don;t think one can come up with better advice until these are done.

Comment: There's a crawler in system for collecting data and it needs Postgresql. Actually I have already optimized Postgresql for my case so I'm not looking for an advice for Postgresql, I'm looking for another solutions like mongodb, riak or solr.